# Odd behavior of function with variable number of parameters in C

Tags: c, list, arguments, stdout, variable-length

I have the following C function with a variable number of arguments, which is supposed to search the `char* word` through a hashtable and write `true` or `false` in a file which, if specified, is the second parameter; otherwise, it is `stdout`.

It works fine if I specify the name of the file, the problem is when I don't (e.g. `find("foo")`). In this case it writes the result in a file named `foo` instead of `stdout`.

What is the cause?

```
void find(char* word, ...)
{
va_list list;
char *fname = NULL;
va_start(list, word);
FILE* f;
fname = strdup(va_arg(list, char*));
va_end(list);
if (<condition>)    // condition suited for the case in which the file name is received 
    f = fopen(fname, "a");
else
    f = stdout;
if (member(word))
    fprintf(f, "True\n");
else
    fprintf(f, "False\n");
}
```

In place of `<condition>` I've tried `fname != NULL` and `strlen(fname) > 0` but those don't apply and it keeps seeing `fname` as `word` when `fname` is not specified.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Comment: varargs are not supposed be used this way. You are better off using `void find(char* word, char* filename)` and checking if `filename` is `NULL` and if so write to stdout. Also don't forget to close the file, you opened, if you did open a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `va_*`'s man page:

> **If  there  is  no next argument**, or if type is not compatible with the
>   type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default
>   argument promotions), **random errors will occur**.

If you want to use a variable parameter list, you need to devise some sort of terminator for the list (e.g., always add a dummy NULL argument):

```
find (word, NULL);
find (word, filename, NULL);
```

or supply the number of parameter as parameter:

```
find (1, word);
find (2, word, filename);
```

Comment: OK, thanks for remembering me. It works with NULL at the end of the list. Initially I thought that NULL (or other behavior) was somehow implied for arguments that weren't received, but it doesn't know by itself when the list ends.